Why don't electrons measure each other in the YDSE?
Why don't electrons measure each other in the YDSE?
Assuming that the electrons are emitted as a spray and not one by one (which I think is reasonable), why don't two electrons measure each other through physical collision/electromagnetic interaction, and collapse each other's wavefunctions?
What part of a valid measurement is this interaction missing?

In case anyone else is confused, I am assuming YDSE = Young's Double Slit Experiment, but carried out with electrons rather than light.

How would they decide what attribute to measure?

A measurement is an irreversible energy transfer to a second system. You have to specify what that second system is.

If the experiment is designed to show the behavior of single independent free electrons, they must be emitted one-by-one.

Whether or not the electrons in the double slit experiment interact with each other depends on the specifics of the experiment. For example, this paper describes a setup with a low-intensity electron beam:

The electron source’s intensity was reduced so that the electron detection rate
in the pattern was about 1 Hz. At this rate and kinetic energy, the average distance
between consecutive electrons was 2.3 × 106 meters. This ensures that only one electron
is present in the 1 meter long system at any one time, thus eliminating electron-electron
interactions.

As for the case with interactions, it really cannot be stressed enough that interactions between the particles in a system do not in general collapse the wavefunction. They merely alter the time evolution of the wavefunction, according to the Schrödinger equation:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}=H\Psi$$
In the case of two electrons interacting via the Coulomb potential*, we get:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,t)=\left[ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_1^2-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_2^2+\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{|\textbf{r}_1-\textbf{r}_2|} \right]\Psi(\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,t)$$
The wavefunction only collapses once the particles are measured by our detector. Unlike the interaction between the electrons, collapse is not (naively) described by the Scrödinger equation. This presents us with a question: what counts as a measurement, and what doesn't? This is called the measurement problem, and it has no universally agreed upon solution. If you desparately need an answer to the measurement problem, pick your favourite interpretation** of quantum mechanics, and get ready to argue with physicists and philosophers for the rest of time.
Some end notes:
$*$ You mention "physical collision" as a way electrons interact. Keep in mind that what we, on a macroscopic scale, consider collisions (such as one billiard ball hitting another) is actually just a result of the microscopic forces between particles.
$**$ Really though, the exact specifics of what constitutes a measurement are largely irrelevant to most physics. The point is that most interactions don't collapse the wave function.

It is not the average distance between quanta that makes a difference. It is the correlation at the source. We can show this perfectly with entanglement experiments. There is no problem with the self-interaction of electron beams in free space at these current densities. What counts as a measurement can be answered in classical mechanics: it requires an irreversible energy exchange. That is exactly the definition of measurement that leads to the Born rule: we need a second system and the quantum of energy has to be transferred from the quantum system to this second measurement system.

My answer does not mention the average distance between quanta so I'm not sure what relevance this has. As for the measurement problem: you might have your own point of view, but that does not mean that everyone else shares it. I intentionally kept my answer agnostic. To promote my own opinions to someone who doesn't know any better would be deceptive.

"the average distance between consecutive electrons was 2.3 × 106 meters" in your quote. That's totally irrelevant for quantum mechanics by definition. My "point of view" about measurement is that of an experimental physicist. One can't do a measurement without irreversible energy transfer. It has to be irreversible by definition because we need a lasting record and it has to be a finite amount of energy because every measurement system has a thermodynamic temperature T>0 and so we have to get E>kT to distinguish measurement results from thermal noise.

@Sturrum thank you for the answer. Interpretations and mathematics of measurements aside, are there some parameters/ conditions that must be satisfied for a measurement to occur?

If you carry out the double slit experiment with electrons and the electrons are  close enough together then they can interact with other electrons by exchanging photons. In this case the electrons become entangled and have a joint quantum state, and it is not surprising that they produce an interference pattern on the screen.
What is more surprising (from a classical point of view) is that an interference pattern is still built up over time when electrons (or photons) are generated one at a time, and do not have any opportunity to become entangled with earlier or later particles.

The general structure of the interference pattern of the double slut does not depend on what we are using. The reason for that is extremely simple: it is, in all cases, produced by the fact that we are measuring the flow of energy. The particular choice of field that carries that energy is irrelevant. That it happens at all intensities is a consequence of quantum of the fact that quantum mechanics is a theory of statistically independent ensembles. Ensemble member are never interacting with each other.

I'm trying to understand how two free electrons, repelling each other through the Coulomb force, somehow become 'entangled', which then results in the interference pattern.
